# I have deployed an django app in pythonanywhere but its not working

Tags: python, django, deployment, pythonanywhere

I have deployed a django(django=1.7,python=2.7) project in  [pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com) but its not working.Its link is - http://drchitradhawle.pythonanywhere.com/
I have installed an virtual enviroment and django(1.7) from bash, then uploaded the project from github, and changed WSGI file. But still its not working.

My WSGI file is-

```
 # TURN ON THE VIRTUAL ENVIRONMENT FOR YOUR APPLICATION
activate_this = '/home/DrChitraDhawle/.virtualenvs/rango/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
import os
import sys

# ADD YOUR PROJECT TO THE PYTHONPATH FOR THE PYTHON INSTANCE
path = '/home/DrChitraDhawle/website/'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

# IMPORTANTLY GO TO THE PROJECT DIR
os.chdir(path)

# TELL DJANGO WHERE YOUR SETTINGS MODULE IS LOCATED
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'website.settings')

# IMPORT THE DJANGO SETUP - NEW TO 1.7
import django
django.setup()

# IMPORT THE DJANGO WSGI HANDLER TO TAKE CARE OF REQUESTS
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

My error log is -

```
2015-03-08 13:06:58,600 :django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
2015-03-08 13:26:48,067 :/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py:1160: RuntimeWarning: tp_compare didn't return -1 or -2 for exception
2015-03-08 13:26:48,068 :  return _active[_get_ident()]
2015-03-08 13:26:48,068 :Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-03-08 13:26:48,068 :  File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 130, in __call__
2015-03-08 13:26:48,068 :    self.error_log_file.logger.exception("Error running WSGI application")
2015-03-08 13:26:48,068 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1185, in exception
2015-03-08 13:26:48,068 :    self.error(msg, *args, **kwargs)
2015-03-08 13:26:48,068 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1178, in error
2015-03-08 13:26:48,069 :    self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)
2015-03-08 13:26:48,069 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1270, in _log
2015-03-08 13:26:48,069 :    record = self.makeRecord(self.name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func, extra)
2015-03-08 13:26:48,069 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1244, in makeRecord
2015-03-08 13:26:48,069 :    rv = LogRecord(name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func)
2015-03-08 13:26:48,069 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 284, in __init__
2015-03-08 13:26:48,069 :    self.threadName = threading.current_thread().name
2015-03-08 13:26:48,069 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 1160, in currentThread
2015-03-08 13:26:48,070 :    return _active[_get_ident()]
2015-03-08 13:26:48,070 :  File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 122, in __call__
2015-03-08 13:26:48,070 :    app_iterator = self.app(environ, start_response)
2015-03-08 13:26:48,070 :  File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 136, in import_error_application
2015-03-08 13:26:48,070 :    raise e
2015-03-08 13:26:48,070 :django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
2015-03-08 13:26:52,598 :Traceback (most recent call last):
2015-03-08 13:26:52,598 :  File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 130, in __call__
2015-03-08 13:26:52,598 :    self.error_log_file.logger.exception("Error running WSGI application")
2015-03-08 13:26:52,598 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1185, in exception
2015-03-08 13:26:52,598 :    self.error(msg, *args, **kwargs)
2015-03-08 13:26:52,599 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1178, in error
2015-03-08 13:26:52,599 :    self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)
2015-03-08 13:26:52,599 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1270, in _log
2015-03-08 13:26:52,599 :    record = self.makeRecord(self.name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func, extra)
2015-03-08 13:26:52,599 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1244, in makeRecord
2015-03-08 13:26:52,600 :    rv = LogRecord(name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func)
2015-03-08 13:26:52,600 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 284, in __init__
2015-03-08 13:26:52,600 :    self.threadName = threading.current_thread().name
2015-03-08 13:26:52,600 :  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 1160, in currentThread
2015-03-08 13:26:52,600 :    return _active[_get_ident()]
2015-03-08 13:26:52,601 :  File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 122, in __call__
2015-03-08 13:26:52,601 :    app_iterator = self.app(environ, start_response)
2015-03-08 13:26:52,601 :  File "/bin/user_wsgi_wrapper.py", line 136, in import_error_application
2015-03-08 13:26:52,601 :    raise e
2015-03-08 13:26:52,601 :django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

In my error log there is error - secret key in settings.py cant be empty, But actually it is not empty.

Server log is -

```
2015-03-08 13:26:44 Sun Mar  8 13:26:44 2015 - received message 1 from emperor
2015-03-08 13:26:44 ...gracefully killing workers...
2015-03-08 13:26:44 Gracefully killing worker 1 (pid: 25092)...
2015-03-08 13:26:45 worker 1 buried after 1 seconds
2015-03-08 13:26:45 uWSGI: GAME OVER (insert coin)
2015-03-08 13:26:45 chdir(): No such file or directory [core/uwsgi.c line 1541]
2015-03-08 13:26:45 VACUUM: unix socket /var/sockets/drchitradhawle.pythonanywhere.com/socket removed.
2015-03-08 13:26:48 *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.5.1 (64bit) on [Sun Mar  8 13:26:45 2015] ***
2015-03-08 13:26:48 compiled with version: 4.8.2 on 13 November 2014 13:45:53
2015-03-08 13:26:48 os: Linux-3.13.0-39-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 28 13:30:27 UTC 2014
2015-03-08 13:26:48 nodename: harry-liveweb2
2015-03-08 13:26:48 machine: x86_64
2015-03-08 13:26:48 clock source: unix
2015-03-08 13:26:48 pcre jit disabled
2015-03-08 13:26:48 detected number of CPU cores: 4
2015-03-08 13:26:48 current working directory: /etc/uwsgi/vassals
2015-03-08 13:26:48 detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
2015-03-08 13:26:48 *** dumping internal routing table ***
2015-03-08 13:26:48 [rule: 0] subject: path_info regexp: \.svgz$ action: addheader:Content-Encoding:gzip
2015-03-08 13:26:48 *** end of the internal routing table ***
2015-03-08 13:26:48 using Linux cgroup /mnt/cgroups/cpu/user_types/free with mode 700
2015-03-08 13:26:48 assigned process 22535 to cgroup /mnt/cgroups/cpu/user_types/free/tasks
2015-03-08 13:26:48 using Linux cgroup /mnt/cgroups/cpuacct/users/DrChitraDhawle with mode 700
2015-03-08 13:26:48 assigned process 22535 to cgroup /mnt/cgroups/cpuacct/users/DrChitraDhawle/tasks
2015-03-08 13:26:48 using Linux cgroup /mnt/cgroups/memory/user_types/free with mode 700
2015-03-08 13:26:48 assigned process 22535 to cgroup /mnt/cgroups/memory/user_types/free/tasks
2015-03-08 13:26:48 uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
2015-03-08 13:26:48 chroot() to /mnt/chroots/DrChitraDhawle
2015-03-08 13:26:48 setgid() to 60000
2015-03-08 13:26:48 setuid() to 749552
2015-03-08 13:26:48 limiting number of processes to 15...
2015-03-08 13:26:48 your processes number limit is 15
2015-03-08 13:26:48 your memory page size is 4096 bytes
2015-03-08 13:26:48 detected max file descriptor number: 123456
2015-03-08 13:26:48 building mime-types dictionary from file /etc/mime.types...
2015-03-08 13:26:48 536 entry found
2015-03-08 13:26:48 lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
2015-03-08 13:26:48 thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
2015-03-08 13:26:48 uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /var/sockets/drchitradhawle.pythonanywhere.com/socket fd 7
2015-03-08 13:26:48 Python version: 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 23:03:41)  [GCC 4.8.2]
2015-03-08 13:26:48 *** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
2015-03-08 13:26:48 Python main interpreter initialized at 0x245a920
2015-03-08 13:26:48 your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
2015-03-08 13:26:48 your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
2015-03-08 13:26:48 setting request body buffering size to 65536 bytes
2015-03-08 13:26:48 mapped 333952 bytes (326 KB) for 1 cores
2015-03-08 13:26:48 *** Operational MODE: single process ***
2015-03-08 13:26:48 WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 3 seconds on interpreter 0x245a920 pid: 22535 (default app)
2015-03-08 13:26:48 *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
2015-03-08 13:26:48 spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 22535)
2015-03-08 13:26:48 spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 22537, cores: 1)
2015-03-08 13:26:48 spawned 2 offload threads for uWSGI worker 1
2015-03-08 13:26:48 announcing my loyalty to the Emperor...
```

Setting.py file with no database is -

```
   """
    Django settings for website project.

    For more information on this file, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/

    For the full list of settings and their values, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/
    """

    # Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
    import os
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


    # Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

    # SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
    SECRET_KEY = 'fi+9..............................j4yvl0tp'


    # SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
    DEBUG = True

    TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


    # Application definition

    INSTALLED_APPS = (
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'webpage',
    )

    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    )

    ROOT_URLCONF = 'website.urls'

    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'website.wsgi.application'


    # Database not required

    # Internationalization
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

    TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

    USE_I18N = True

    USE_L10N = True

    USE_TZ = True


    STATIC_ROOT = "/home/DrChitraDhawle/website/webpage/static"

   STATIC_URL = '/static/'

   STATICFILES_DIR = (
    ('assets', '/home/DrChitraDhawle/website/webpage'),
    )


    MEDIA_URL = 'http://localhost:8085/media/'
```

> static file settings at web tab -

[image: static file settings at web tab]

Note :- My static file is at location-
home/DrChitraDhawle/website/webpage/static/css

Comment: Way to *"keep the secret key used in production secret!"*...

Comment: sorry, whats the error?

Comment: Hi Rahul, just to clarify, what jonrsharpe meant was that you shouldn't show the secret key to stack overflow, because that key is used for encryption etc in your webapp.

However, you would still need that key for your website to deploy correctly.

Comment: Thanks for suggession, i will hide it.

Comment: Also- to use a virtual env, you need to put the virtualenv path into the webapp configs. Did you do that?

What I mean by that is that you should be putting "/home/DrChitraDhawle/.virtualenvs/rango" into a section called virtualenvs under your web tab.

Comment: No i have just put that path in my WSGI file not in webapp configs

Comment: Another quick check- have you reloaded your webapp since adding the secret key back in?

Comment: I have now put the path of virtualenv in the place you told, but it still not working. Also i have uploaded my secret key with my whole project and since then i haven't changed it .

Comment: @conrad please help me to find out the error.It still not working.

Comment: hmm. a couple other checks, just grasping at straws- you have run syncdb and created a database already right?

Comment: and you don't try to import settings.py anywhere else resulting in a circular import?

Comment: I haven't used syncdb as i don't want to use databases.

Comment: OOH i just took a look at your wsgi file. It is different from the wsgi file you posted above. 
In particular, `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'website.settings')` is just `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'website')`.
You want the .settings one

Comment: keep in mind that the wsgi file in question is the one under your webtab interface (`/var/www/drchitradhawle_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py`), in case you are confusing it with anything else

Comment: You want to say that i should change my os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'website.settings') file to os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'website')    but it still getting same error of secret key

Comment: but i am already having the same as - os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'website.settings')

Comment: I am referring to the file in `/var/www/drchitradhawle_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py`, which is the file you should be looking at if you go to the web tab. Or the file if you go here https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/DrChitraDhawle/files/var/www/drchitradhawle_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py?edit

You do not have .settings in the file.

Comment: It worked! But still having some problem you can see it in link - http://drchitradhawle.pythonanywhere.com/     I think its bootstrap and static files not working

Comment: @conrad thanks for your answer, i am very happy that something is visible. Now plz help me to sort out the problem.

Comment: You need to set up your static files to be served. See https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/DjangoStaticFiles , 

https://www.pythonanywhere.com/wiki/StaticFiles

and http://blog.pythonanywhere.com/60/ for more info

Comment: I have done accordingly but on running command python manage.py collectstatic output is- 61 static files copied to '/home/DrChitraDhawle/website/webpage/static', 12 unmodified. And it still not working

Comment: I have updated changes made in setting.py above also i have added an image of link of static files. The path of static folder on my project is home/DrChitraDhawle/website/webpage/static  .plz find out the error.

Comment: Are you sure you have setup the static files correct? As an admin looking at your configs, I see a couple problems. Compare your setup to this http://blog.pythonanywhere.com/static/images/static-files-for-eliza-suitcase.jpg

Comment: Sir i have changed  the static file setting  as link provided by you and it still not working. I have updated the image, please find out the error.

Comment: Hey @conrad my problem isnt solved yet also i have made another question for that plz ans it. link to new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28940098/error-in-linking-static-files-in-django-project-deployed-on-pythonanywhere

Comment: If you compare the picture to your static file settings you will see that there is still a difference... (you are missing the the "/" from `/home`)